# Javascirpt Array Sorting Problem in reactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to create an Accordion using material UI in my react project. The challenges I have faced is I need to separate data where pageNumber is same. Like here is my array below

```
let myArr=[{string:"Text One",pageNumber:1},{string:"Text Two",pageNumber:1},{string:"Text Three",pageNumber:2},{string:"Text Four",pageNumber:3},]
```

So when I will loop my array I will not create new accordion if I found multiple same pageNumber. Like I will make one accordion for pageNumber 1 and New For pageNumber 2 and pageNumber 3.

pageNumber 1 will contain all string in the accordion body. how Can I loop like that in react JSX template ? Thank you

Comment: This looks like a JS problem than React.  Can you show any code you may have tried?

Comment: I just tried to sort them out, but failed, here is my code, 

`
for(let i=0; i<newarr.length; i++){
     
  let firstTemp=newarr[i].pageNumber;
  let secondTemp=newarr.slice(-2, -1)[0].pageNumber;
  let count=0;
  
  console.log(firstTemp,secondTemp)
  
  if(firstTemp === secondTemp){
    count++;
    
    //console.log(newarr[i]);
    
     console.log("Div Created",newarr[i].pageNumber);
     
  }else{
    console.log("Accordation Created");
    
  }
   
  
 }

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work, you can first re-work the array by creating a map of pageNumber => array(string) this way you can loop through it based on the page number.
An possible solution can be the following:

```
    let myArr=[{string:"Text One",pageNumber:1},{string:"Text Two",pageNumber:1},{string:"Text Three",pageNumber:2},{string:"Text Four",pageNumber:3},];
    let allAccordions = [];

    let mapped = {};
    myArr.forEach(({string, pageNumber}) => {
        if (!Array.isArray(mapped[pageNumber])) {
            mapped[pageNumber] = [];
        }
        mapped[pageNumber].push(string);
    });

    console.log(mapped); // {1:['Text One', 'Text Two'], 2: ['Text Three'...]}

    Object.keys(mapped).forEach(key => { // key = 1,2,3,4
        let strings = mapped[key]; // strings = ['Text One', 'Text Two']
        
        // create accorion content
        let accordionContent = strings.map(string => {
            return `<div class="accordion-content">${string}</div>`;
        });

        // make main accordion
        let accordion = `<div class="accodrion">${accordionContent}</div>`;
        
        // add to accordions
        allAccordions.push(accordion)
    });

    console.log(allAccordions);
```

You can now print the allAccordions in the react jsx component as ${allAccordions}.